# Can't make CMS admin for my blog

Tags: php, mysql, database, content-management-system, admin

This is the php program I created to insert data into the database.

```
<?php    
  include '../includes/config.php';
  //Input Data Process
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
  if (isset($_POST["post"])) {
    $title = $_POST["title"];
    $description = $_POST["description"];
    $article = $_POST["article"];
    mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO post VALUES('','$title','$description','$article')");
    header("location:index.php?article");
  }
  $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM post");    
?>
```

But when I hit the post button **nothing happens** in the database.

This is config.php file.

```
<?php    
  //Database Connection
  global $conn;

  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";
  $db = "my_blog";

  $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);

  //Check Connection
  if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection Failed : ".mysqli_connect_error());
  }    
?>
```

Comment: Nothing happens? What is meant to happen? Also, have a look at this, in terms of writing questions that are easier to answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Are you getting any error message.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the column names in your `INSERT`. For example:

```
INSERT INTO post (column1, column2, column3, column4) VALUES ('', '$title', '$description', '$article')
```

**Note:** Technically, you can skip the column names if you are adding values for all the columns of the table. In this case, you also need to make sure that the order of the values is in the same order as the columns in the table.